# Laravel import view class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am learning Laravel and I am a bit confused.
PHPStorm offers me several view import options, which one should I choose?

[image]

I have tried using `use Illuminate\View\View;` ,also several controllers are using`use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;` or `use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;`

They all seem to work in the same manner, which one is the correct way to import view class?
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#creating-and-rendering-views

Comment: I have checked this and found nothing about my question. I know I can use View Facade but that is not the point. I can also see the usage of Illuminate\View\View but there might be better way to do this and that is why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

use Façade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

as return type use

```
 use Illuminate\View\View;
```

For more https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#creating-and-rendering-views

Comment: I prefer not to use Facades and that is why I am asking for the correct way of importing that other view classes.

Comment: so what u want to achieve , to render view you have to use  the view façade

Comment: I am using: return view("dashboard"); so not facade and wondering which import is correct as I have several to choose from and all seem to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: then use `use Illuminate\View\View;`